# How to filter an elasticsearch global aggregation?

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation

What I want to achieve: I want my "age" aggregation to not be filtered by the query filter and I want to be able to apply filters to it.

So if I start with this query:

```json
{
    "query":{
        "filtered":{
            "filter":{ "terms":{ "family_name":"Brown" } } //filter_1
        }
    },
    "aggs":{
        "young_age":{
            "filter":{
                "range":{ "lt":40, "gt":18 } //filter_2
            },
            "aggs":{
                "age":{
                    "terms":{
                        "field":"age"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

My aggregation "young_age" will be filtered by both filter_1 and filter_2. I don't want my aggregation to be filtered by filter_1.

As I was looking into the documentation, I thought global aggregation would solve my problem, and I wrote that query:

```json
{
    "query":{
        "filtered":{
            "filter":{ "terms":{ "family_name":"Brown" } } //filter_1
        }
    },
    "aggs":{
        "young_age":{
            "global":{}, //<----------- add global
            "filter":{
                "range":{ "lt":40, "gt":18 } //filter_2
            },
            "aggs":{
                "age":{
                    "terms":{
                        "field":"age"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But then elastic search complains about my filter_2:

"""
Found two aggregation type definitions [age] in [global] and [filter]
"""

And of course if I remove the filter_2:

```json
{
    "query":{
        "filtered":{
            "filter":{
                "terms":{
                    "family_name":"Brown"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "aggs":{
        "young_age":{
            "global":{},
            "aggs":{
                "age":{
                    "terms":{
                        "field":"age"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then my aggregation won't be filtered by filter_1 (as expected).

So how am I suppose to apply filter_2 to my global aggregation? Or how am I supposed to achieved that? I remember writing something similar with the facet filters...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

In my opinion this is the typical use case of a [post_filter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-post-filter.html). As the doc says:

> The post_filter is applied to the search hits at the very end of a search request, after aggregations have already been calculated

Your query will look like:

```json
{
    "post_filter":{
       "terms":{
            "family_name":"Brown" //filter_1
        }
    },
   "aggs":{
        "young_age":{
            "filter":{
                "range":{ "lt":40, "gt":18 } //filter_2
            },
            "aggs":{
                "age":{
                    "terms":{
                        "field":"age"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

In this case the search hits are all the documents in the index. Then the aggregation is calculated (before filter_1). And after that the `post_filter` with the filter_1 will be executed.

Edit: As you said in your commend you have many aggregations and only one that shouldn't be affected by `filter_1` I fixed your query using global aggregation

```json
{
  "query": {
    "filtered": {
      "filter": {
        "term": {
          "family_name": "Brown"
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "young_age": {
      "global": {},
      "aggs": {
        "filter2": {
          "filter": {
            "range": {
              "lt": 40,
              "gt": 18
            }
          },
          "aggs": {
            "age": {
              "terms": {
                "field": "age"
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That would work but actually I've got many aggregations and only one of them shouldn't be filtered by filter_1. So with your solution that means that I would have to replicate the post_filter for those aggregations which I find a bit annoying (and also maybe not that good from the performance point of view?)

Comment: @adrienbourgeois I fixed the query using global aggregation, let me know if it works for you :)

Comment: Thanks mate it's working like a charm! I've accepted your answer. cheers

Comment: Thank you for the second (edited) answer. I was losing my head until I found your filtered sub-aggregation idea.

Answer (score 1):

globals and filters are not allowed at same level. you have to put filter at one level inside to global aggregation.

something like this should do for you.

```json
{
    "query":{
        "filtered":{
            "filter":{
                "terms":{
                    "family_name":"Brown"
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "aggs":{
        "young_age":{
            "global":{},
            "aggs":{
                "filter": {"term": {"family_name": "Brown"}}, #or {"bool": {"filter": {"term": {"family_name": "Brown"}}}}
                "aggs": {
                    "age":{
                        "terms":{
                            "field":"age"
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```