# In Elasticsearch, how to apply filters at an aggregation level

Tags: java, elasticsearch, aggregate

I am currently using termsfilter and then aggregation to filter the hits and then apply aggregations. Is there a way that i can have one common filter for all the aggregations and one filter at an aggregation level (Terms Aggregation)?

Note : I am not looking for Aggregation Filter/Filter's as it won't return buckets on required field and I am not looking for post_filter.

Thanks in Advance..

Comment: Please show your current query, the results you're getting and what you expect instead. The more info you provide the better the chances of getting people to answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer from some other question 
[How to filter an elasticsearch global aggregation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31670668/how-to-filter-an-elasticsearch-global-aggregation)

```
{
    "query":{
        "filtered":{
            "filter":{ "terms":{ "family_name":"Brown" } } //filter_1
        }
    },
    "aggs":{
        "young_age":{
            "filter":{
                "range":{ "lt":40, "gt":18 } //filter_2
            },
            "aggs":{
                "age":{
                    "terms":{
                        "field":"age"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```